# Check if connection to SQL Server is available with classic ASP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a web app in classic ASP that most run at all times. The problem is that sometimes our internet connection is bad. If the web app can't connect to SQL Server I want to save it on a local server instead. So my question is:

How can I with classic ASP check if a connection to an external SQL Server is live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%
    set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    on error resume next
    conn.open "remote connection string"
    if err.number <> 0 then
        response.write "unable to connect, trying other"
        conn.open "alternate connection string"
    end if
    on error goto 0
%>
```

Comment: I think the timeout is like 90 seconds so maybe you'd need to lower that.

Comment: @svinto The default was 15 back when I was cranking out ASP stuff... maybe it has changed since then? Or maybe you're thinking of CommandTimeout, not ConnectionTimeout? Though CommandTimeout was also lower (30 seconds IIRC).

Comment: `err.Description` will give you error message, This is helpful when you do not have access to view ASP error.